# Specific xpath for flipkart website

Tags: xpath, webdriver

I am trying to frame xpath for selecting add to compare in flipkart search site for below text.
**Apple iPhone SE Gold, 32 GB**

I was successful till some extent after which the browser is not identifying elements.

The url of webpage is

https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/~iphone-se-32gb/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=clp_banner_2_5.bannerX3.BANNER_apple-products-store_9QKULU32C6_wp5&fm=neo%2Fmerchandising&iid=M_cf50b8ba-6d96-4c69-942d-86066743d3a2_5.9QKULU32C6

Below is my xml path

```
  //div[text()='Apple iPhone SE (Gold, 32 GB)' and @class='_3wU53n']/parent::div/parent::div
```

But if i want to go further to parent

```
 //div[text()='Apple iPhone SE (Gold, 32 GB)' and @class='_3wU53n']/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div
```

Its showing me 0 results.
Basically i want to go till input type=checkbox.

I am attaching the image of xml as i don't know how to copy the entire xml.
Please help me.

[image: Image of the xml]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify xpath as follows (I'm gonna split it in multiline just to make it more readable)

```
//div[text()='Apple iPhone SE (Gold, 32 GB)']
/parent::div
/parent::div
/preceding-sibling::div
//input[@type='checkbox']
```

By the way this path is quite "fragile" due its structure